# Django Model Design many-to-one?

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, one-to-many, many-to-one

I'm trying to create two models in Django, 'Paragraph' and 'Sentences'. I still do not seem to understand how the many-to-one function works. If I want there to be a paragraph that holds multiple sentences; do I simply add a ForeignKey(Paragraph) into the Sentences model? That way I can have more than one sentence store inside the Paragraph model.
Thank you for any insight as I try to learn Django.

```
    class Sentence(models.Model):
        text = models.TextField(blank=True)
        order_number = models.IntegerField()
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.text
    
    class Paragraph(models.Model):
        text = models.TextField(blank=True)
        order_number = models.IntegerField()
        sentences = models.ForeignKey(Sentence, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.text
```

Comment: Please show your models

Comment: Yes, you are on the right track. A Paragraph can have many Sentences, but a Sentence can only have one Paragraph. Sentence therefore has a foreign key to its Paragraph. You can retrieve the Sentences of a Paragraph by doing `Para.sentence_set.all()` where `Para` is the Paragraph object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ForeignKey` is a *many-to-one* relation. That means that *multiple* items where you define the model can link to the same item of the *target* model.

Therefore `Paragraph` is thus the "parent" model, and `Sentence` the "child" model:

```
class Paragraph(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(blank=True)
    order_number = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

class Sentence(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(blank=True)
    order_number = models.IntegerField()
    paragraph = models.ForeignKey(
        Paragraph,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='sentences'
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

You thus can make a `Paragraph` and multiple sentences that all link to the same paragraph:

```
p1 = Paragraph.objects.create(text='Act 3, Scene 1', order_number=0)
s1 = Sentence.objects.create(
    text='To be, or not to be, that is the question',
    paragraph=p1,
    order_number=0
)
s2 = Sentence.objects.create(
    text='Whether 'tis nobler in the mind to suffer',
    paragraph=p1,
    order_number=1
)
```

You can then query all the *related* sentences of `p1` with:

```
p1.sentences.all()
```